# isPostBack as Query Parameter

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I created an ASPX page with search controls to the left bound as controls for an AccessDataSource.

I want the data grid to be blank on the first calling of the page, but show the results for subsequent page loads.

I plan to achieve this by putting `[pFirstRun] = False` as my first `WHERE` condition with the parameter `pFirstRun` tied to the value isPostBack.  How do I achieve this?

Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OnSelecting event of your datasource and so something like this for your code infront:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" OnSelecting="AccessDataSource1_Selecting"/>
```

And something like this in your code-behind:

```
protected void AccessDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could put the code where you do the databind() on the datagrid within a

```
if (!Page.IsPostback){}
```

Comment: if the accessdatasource is defined in the code infront you don't need to call databind() so this wont help